# is it possible to hover over header tag with tailwind?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I need the text to scale big when I hover over them,

**Code :**

```
function Startpage() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-mygraymain">
      <div className="flex justify-center">
        <h1 className="hover:scale-125">Hi,Sai</h1>
      </div>
);
}
```

But then the above code doesn't work. Changing background, underline work with hover but couldn't scale.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `transform` class also as Tailwind docs [says](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/scale):

> Scale - Control the scale of an element by first enabling transforms with the transform utility, then specifying the scale using the scale-{percentage}, scale-x-{percentage}, and scale-y-{percentage} utilities.